# Mathematica - Solve equation as an expression of two variables

Tags: variables, wolfram-mathematica

Simple question, all I want to do is have Solve[] work in a way that instead of solving for a single variable (eg. Vo) it solves for the expression Vo/Vi. In all cases this just equates to dividing both sides by Vi, as it'll cancel out on the RHS anyway, curious if there's a quick way to do it though.

Thanks

EDIT: Here's the code

```
vd = 0 - V1;
VL = Solve[(V1 - Vi)/R1 + (V1 - Vo)/R2 == 0, V1][[All, 1, 2]][[1]];
VR = Solve[(Vo - V1)/R2 + (Vo - (AO*vd))/RO == 0, V1][[All, 1, 2]][[1]];
Av = Solve[VL == VR, Vo][[All, 1, 2]][[1]];
Av = Av/Vi //I add this to remove the Vi
```

Basically I want it to solve for Vo/Vi, to automatically remove the Vi from the RHS...

Comment: Please write down a piece of Mathematica code we can grab to be sure that we are understanding your question properly

Comment: Code is up there now, let me know if you still have trouble understandnig what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `V1` as a placeholder in `Solve` to get `VL` and `VR`.  Let's get rid of `V1` by putting `VL` and `VR` directly into those equations.  This means that we also need to define `vd` as `0 - VR`.

Also, let's define `Av` as `Vo/Vi`.

We can stuff all of the equations into `Eliminate`, asking it to eliminate `Vo`, `Vi`, `VL`, `VR`, and `vd`:

```
In[72]:= Eliminate[
 vd == 0 - VR
  && (VL - Vi)/R1 + (VL - Vo)/R2 == 0
  && (Vo - VR)/R2 + (Vo - (AO*vd))/RO == 0
  && VL == VR
  && Av == Vo/Vi,
 {Vo, Vi, vd, VL, VR}]

Out[72]= Av (1 + AO + R2/R1 + RO/R1) == (-AO R2 + RO)/R1 && R1 != 0 &&
  R2 != 0 && RO != 0
```

That's pretty close to what we want, but it's not quite solved for `Av`, so let's do that too:

```
In[73]:= Solve[
 Eliminate[
  vd == 0 - VR
   && (VL - Vi)/R1 + (VL - Vo)/R2 == 0
   && (Vo - VR)/R2 + (Vo - (AO*vd))/RO == 0
   && VL == VR
   && Av == Vo/Vi,
  {Vo, Vi, vd, VL, VR}],
 Av]

Out[73]= {{Av -> (-AO R2 + RO)/(R1 + AO R1 + R2 + RO)}}
```

If you want to actually define the symbol `Av`, we can do that using `/.` (`ReplaceAll`):

```
In[80]:= Av =.; Av = Av /. Solve[
    Eliminate[
     vd == 0 - VR
      && (VL - Vi)/R1 + (VL - Vo)/R2 == 0
      && (Vo - VR)/R2 + (Vo - (AO*vd))/RO == 0
      && VL == VR
      && Av == Vo/Vi,
     {Vo, Vi, vd, VL, VR}],
    Av][[1]];

In[81]:= Av

Out[81]= (-AO R2 + RO)/(R1 + AO R1 + R2 + RO)
```